# What does "He who sups with the devil should have a long spoon" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I've recently read this quote somewhere in a book and I can't seem to comprehend it.

Comment: The 'long spoon' means keeping as far away as possible if you must interact in some way with the Devil. Get too close and you'll be in even bigger trouble...

Comment: This question does not show any attempt at research.

Comment: Out of pitchfork range.

Comment: Often used when enemies decide to negotiate. E.g Some people might say it to Obama before he sits down with Rohani.

Comment: The devil transfers his heat to the stew, and a long spoon helps it cool off before it reaches your mouth. Because of the distance. Obviously.

Comment: Did you try pasting that quote into the Google Search box and see what happens? Why not?

Comment: However a long spoon may be hard to use  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PONvX6LmAPo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that you should be very careful if you mix with bad people. The OED’s earliest citation supporting it is this slightly varied form from Chaucer’s ‘Squire’s Tale’:

> Therfore bihoueth hire a ful long spoon That shal ete with a feend.

Comment: That's GR! https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&q=“He+who+sups+with+the+devil+should+have+a+long+spoon”

Answer (score 1):

At face value the logic behind this is that the devil, known to eat people, may just as well decide to eat you along with the food, and the only way to avoid becoming dessert is a with a long spoon to help keep your distance. More figuratively it describes the approach to dealing with dangerous adversaries.

Comment: **1** I am not sure that, in English folklore, the devil was known to eat people. Traditionally, he is interested in filling Hell with lost souls.  **2** "the Devil" was never meant to be taken literally - the Devil" was always understood as an epithet for a disreputable or dangerous person or idea. **3** The *long spoon* refers to the metaphorical distancing of oneself from the defining influence of that person or idea such that one is not contaminated by that reputation/idea.

Answer (score 1):

James Kelly, [*A Complete Collection of Scottish Proverbs: Explained and Made Intelligible to the English Reader*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BEgOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1&source=gbs_selected_pages&hl=en#v=snippet&q=%22spoon%20that%20sups%22&f=false) (1721) offers this succinct explanation of the Scottish version of the proverb:

> *He had need of a long Spoon that sups Kail [broth] with the Dee'l.*
>
> He that has to do with wicked and false Men had need to be cautious, and on his Guard.

The purpose of the (figurative) long spoon is simply to keep as much distance between yourself and the Devil as possible, given the close quarters entailed in dining together—and indeed eating out of the same bowl. You wouldn't want to sit too close to the Devil because you never know when he might decide to try to grab you and whisk you away to Hell with him. Likewise, being in close proximity to wicked people is an invitation to injury at their hands.

---

***Some background on early instances of the proverb and on its international reach***

As Barrie England observes, a version of this proverb appears in Chaucer's "Squire's Tale." "[The Proverbs of Chaucer, with Illustrations from Other Sources](https://books.google.com/books?id=qt84AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22spoon+that+sups%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY0_3hgtnrAhWPHzQIHYt8D-wQ6AEwBXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22spoon%20that%20sups%22&f=false)," in *Scottish Notes and Queries* (September 1893) provides additional coverage of early instances of the saying and of similar sayings in other languages:

> "Therfor bihoveth him a ful long spoon / That shal ete with a feeend," thus herde I seye. *Squires T.*, l. 602
> >Compare:
>
> He that eats with the devil hath need of a long spoon. —*Hazlitt*.
>
> He needs a long-shanket spoon that sups kail wi' the deil.—*Hislop*.
>
> Who dips with the devil he had need of a long spoon.—*Appius and Virginia*, 1575.
>
> Yes, sir, the proverb says he that eats with the devil has need of a long spoon. I have brought you a ladle. —Marlowe's *Jew of Malta*, III. 4.
>
> Marry, he must have a long spoon that must eat with the devil. —[Shakespeare's] *Comedy of Errors*, IV. 3.
> >This is a devil and no monster : I will leave him ; I have no long spoon. —[Shakespeare's] *Tempest*, II. 2.
>
> Hazlitt says this proverb also occurs in Kemp's "Nine Daies Wonder," 1600, and in Overbury's "Characters," appended to the wife, a Jesuit is said to be "a larger spoone for a Traytour to feed with the Devill, then any other Order." The proverb is also found in the collection of Düringfeld and Wander (German), Fallersleben (Old Netherland Proverbs), Man (Danish), and others.

The proverb also appears in David Fergusson, [*Scottish Proverbs*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/B03446.0001.001/1:3?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=spoon;op2=near;q2=Devil) (1641) as

> He should have a long shafted spoon that sups kail with the devil.

Fergusson died in 1598, so the recorded proverb is significantly older than the publication date in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I largely support Barrie England's interpretation.  In the past, one dined with two types of people; those whom one socialized with, and those with whom one expected to do business with (not necessarily exclusive).  Hence, to "dine with the Devil" implies that one is either socializing with the Devil or doing business with him.  If you are merely engaging in trade, it is best to keep one's distance. 
 Get too close, and at best, his foulness will contaminate you.  At worst, he will betray you.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the closer you get to the devil the more you're influenced by them. The same goes for mixing with bad people in your life.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure who first phrased it this way, but this saying goes back to before King Solomon, who was King of Israel from 971-931 B.C.  While King Solomon authored much of the Book of Proverbs, he collected some from other sources.  This saying is based on Proverbs Chapter 23, verses 6-8, which was a collection of proverbs from a group called "the wise."  Proverbs 23:6-8 KJV
"Eat thou not the bread of him that hath an evil eye, neither desire thou his dainty meats: For as he thinketh in his heart, so is he: Eat and drink, saith he to thee; but his heart is not with thee. The morsel which thou hast eaten shalt thou vomit up, and lose thy sweet words."  In other words, if you do sit down to eat with an evil person who may wish you harm, whether Satan or some other evil person, you better use a long spoon to keep some distance or you may live to regret it.

Comment: I see no reference to a long spoon in your quote.

Answer (score -4):

What does “He who sups with the devil should have a long spoon” mean?  The implied meaning is: that person dining with the devil is a bottom feeder... that person is eating from the bottom of the medieval pail after everyone else is served.